# Chakra-ui heading size by heading level in theme

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I'm trying to define the font size for `h` elements in a [Chakra-UI theme](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/customize-theme#customizing-single-components), and for some reason, no matter what I do it's not overriding what I'm assuming is the base theme responsive definitions.

This is in NextJS, pulling content from DatoCMS headless CMS, so the actual instantiation of the `h` elements looks like this:

```
      ...
      renderRule(isHeading, ({ node, children, key }) => {
        return (
          <Heading key={key} as={`h${node.level}`} pt={6} pb={4}>
            {children}
          </Heading>
        );
      }),
      ...
```

If I change it there to, say, `` <Heading key={key} as={`h${node.level}\`} pt={6} pb={4} size=('5xl')> ``, it works fine. My theme also works fine in general (e.g., naming brand color variables, setting the font weight on `Heading` elements), but for some reason, I can't get it to set the size of the headings.

The closest I've gotten is setting the size in the `global` object:

```
const styles = {
    global: (props) => ({
      h1: { fontSize: [null, null, '5xl'] }
    })
}
```

Doing the above at least makes it to the browser, but it gets overridden. In dev tools, the computed css shows

```
@media screen and (min-width: 48em)
.css-fcs9e9 {
  font-size: var(--chakra-fontSizes-4xl);
  line-height: 1.2;
}
.css-fcs9e9 {
  font-family: var(--chakra-fonts-heading);
  font-weight: var(--chakra-fontWeights-light);
  // font-size: var(--chakra-fontSizes-3xl); shown as overridden
  line-height: 1.33;
  padding-top: var(--chakra-space-6);
  padding-bottom: var(--chakra-space-4);
}
@media screen and (min-width: 48em)
h1 {
  // font-size: var(--chakra-fontSizes-5xl); shown as overridden
}
```

I've also tried

setting a single value in `textStyles`:

```
const textStyles = {
    h1: {
        fontSize: '5xl'
    }
}
```

setting an array in `textStyles`:

```
const textStyles = {
    h1: {
        fontSize: [ null, null, '5xl' ]
    }
}
```

setting the `baseStyle` at the component level:

```
const Heading = defineStyleConfig({
    baseStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'light', // this works
        textStyles: { h1: [ null, null, '5xl' ] } // this doesn't work (also for singular `textStyle`
    }
})
```

but none of those three even make it to the browser.

What's the right way to set the text size at the theme level?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to solve this problem in my project:

Setting the `fontSize` does not make it because it gets overridden by the `size` prop, which defaults to `xl`, which in turn applies a specific style (setting `fontSize` and `lineHeight`). You can see the default sizes in the [Heading Theme Source](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/components/theme/src/components/heading.ts).

So the way to get around this, is to specify a custom empty size ("dynamic" in the code below) and create a baseStyle that depends on the `as` prop:

```js
// Define the heading sizes how you like here
const headingSizes = {
  "4xl": defineStyle({
    fontSize: "5xl",
    lineHeight: 1.1,
  }),
  "3xl": defineStyle({
    fontSize: "4xl",
    lineHeight: 1.3,
  }),
  "2xl": defineStyle({
    fontSize: "3xl",
    lineHeight: 1.5,
  }),
  xl: defineStyle({
    fontSize: "2xl",
    lineHeight: 1.7,
  }),
  lg: defineStyle({
    fontSize: "xl",
    lineHeight: 1.8,
  }),
  md: defineStyle({
    fontSize: "lg",
    lineHeight: 1.9,
  }),
  sm: defineStyle({
    fontSize: "md",
    lineHeight: 2,
  }),
  xs: defineStyle({
    fontSize: "sm",
    lineHeight: 2,
  }),
};

// Chakra theme with dynamic heading size based on the "as" prop
const theme: ThemeOverride = {
  components: {
    Heading: {
      baseStyle: ({ as }) => {
        switch (as) {
          case "h1":
            return headingSizes["4xl"];
          case "h2":
            return headingSizes["3xl"];
          case "h3":
            return headingSizes["2xl"];
          case "h4":
            return headingSizes["xl"];
          case "h5":
            return headingSizes["lg"];
          case "h6":
            return headingSizes["md"];
          default:
            return headingSizes["3xl"];
        }
      },
      sizes: {
        dynamic: {},
      },
      defaultProps: {
        size: "dynamic",
      },
    },
  }
};
```

Comment: I think the link to Heading Theme Source is broken, should be: https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/theme/src/components/heading.ts